# How to estimate the size of each coefficient of the result of a polynomial multiplication?

Tags: polynomials

Let $a$ and $b$ be two polynomials of degree $D$. Moreover, suppose the $i$-th coefficient of $a$ and $b$ lies in the range $\left[0, 2^{n_i}\right)$.

Now, let $c = a \cdot b$. This implies that $c_i \in \left[0,2^{m_i}\right)$, for $i \in \mathbb{Z}_{2D}$.

How to compute $m_i$?

Comment: Are you looking for something other than $(0,(N+1)2^{2m})$, which would be achieved by the worst case $a=b=\sum_{i=0}^N 2^m x^i$?

Comment: I'm looking for something more general. Some formulation specialized for each coefficient.

Comment: András Salamon, try now.

Comment: For the case of polynomials in one variable $x$, it sounds as though you are looking for the coefficients of $(\sum_{i=0}^D 2^{n_i} x^i)^2$.